# Converting java.util.Date to java.sql.Timestamp results into wrong value

Tags: java, java.util.date

Server side code (server timezone is UTC):-

```
Date aDate = new Date();
java.sql.Timestamp aTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(aDate.getTime());
```

Client side (Mobile app, timezone GMT +5:30):-

```
Hitting a service request which runs above code on server side
```

The issue is when i debugged on server, found following values :-

```
aDate.getTime() prints to -> 1470472883877 milliseconds i.e., Sat Aug 06 2016 14:11:23 GMT+0530
```

but

```
aTimestamp prints to ->  (java.sql.Timestamp) 2016-08-06 08:41:44.109
```

It's kinda weird, i've no idea what's going on in conversion !! please help

Comment: Can you please post the printing code?

Comment: `System.out.println(aDate.getTime())` and `System.out.println(aTimestamp)` @johnnyaug

Answer (score 1):

UTC and GMT are formats.
 `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` are independent of the timezone. They store a `long time` in ms for representing their inner state.
For information, Calendar is timezone aware.

So with Date or Timestamp, to differentiate GMT or UTC format in an output, you have to use a formater which outputs the date into string by being aware the timezone.

In your output : `2016-08-06 08:41:44.109`, you don't use a formater which is aware of the timezone. It's probably the result of a `toString()` on the `java.sql.Timestamp` instance or something of similar.

What you consider as a conversion is not a conversion but a formatting since the timestamp stays the same between the two objects.

If you want to display in the UTC format, use the appropriate formater with a
SimpleDateFormat for example :

```
SimpleDateFormat dt= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
dt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dateStringInUTC = dt.format(new Date(yourSqlTimestamp.getTime()));
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` are aware of timezones, but both of them returns a **string value** of the date. But i want the output as `date`

Comment: One solution is to parse the string to date using `dateFormat.parse(strDate)`, but i don't want to use it as it increases the probability of `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by " i want the output as date".A output should be a string, no? If what you want is having an date object with the good timestamp, you have already it since as explained what you call a conversion is not a conversion but a formatting.

Comment: If i don't understand your need, don't hesitate to explain what you mean by" i want the output as date"

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably what you are looking for:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);  // use your locale here
Timestamp aTimestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println(aTimestamp);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

And the output:

> 2016-08-06 19:12:54.613
>
> Sat Aug 06 19:12:54 CEST 2016